# DL Query vs. SPARQL Query for complex queries

Tags: sparql, protege

I am beginner in Protege. Could you please tell me which is better for complex queries: DL Query, SPARQL query or Existential Query? For me complex queries refers to, for example, multiple Select Distinct and Where query statements combined.

Comment: What you are referring to as complex queries sounds like sparql. With DL Query I suspect you refer to the DL query tab in Protege. This actually uses the reasoner configured in Protege. As for Existential Query I do not know what mean.

Comment: Yes I am referring to SPARQL ad compared to DL QUERY tab in PROTEGE. Is the DL QUERY syntax capable to create complex queries as SPARQL does?

Comment: Use SPARQL then.